# Access to for loop variable inside another for loop (Django Template)

Tags: django, python-3.x, for-loop, django-templates

I am trying to access a `for` loop variable `i` inside another `for` loop but it doesn't work:

Something like :

```
{% for i in l %}
    {% for j in i %}
        {{ j }}
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

`l`: `list` - Context Variable (like : `l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` )

Comment: It should most certainly work. What is the output you are getting? Try printing the value of `i` before the second `for` to debug it.

Comment: It's working ! when i try to print the value of `i` , i find where is the problem 
thank you